# Few tests fail only docker instance

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have around 60 test cases which runs in sequential. When the test reaches 50 plus then the remaining test cases fail at application log in page itself. Not sure what is happening in the docker.the 50-60 test case series works fine in my local and in docker when run individually. this issue occurs only when the full test suite  is run in a sequential way

Comment: Please describe the issue you encountered in greater detail and include the full error message. The current information is not enough to diagnose the problem. You may also find helpful information in the following FAQ entry about the container resource shortage: [FAQ: Container Resources](https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#not-enough-resources-in-the-container-or-ci-system).

Comment: Are you running your tests against the production environment? or an environment that is defended to detect bot activity?

Comment: No not a production environment It is just a QA env and i confirmed with Devops that there is no such restriction